# Why is slice_min() slow?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, dplyr

Consider a data frame `dat` with a `group` variable, and with one observation or more of `x` per group. Assume no ties in `x` within groups. One way to extract the observation that minimizes `x` within each `group` is to use `dplyr::slice_min()`.

I like that `slice_min()` clearly expresses my intent, but it's often painfully slow, as below. I'd expect slower performance when arranging values of `x` within groups (more complex than finding the minimum). How come it's so much faster? Even my strange use of `summarize()` below is much faster!

More specifically, I'd like to maintain good performance with n groups and O(1) observations per group, as n tends to infinity.

```
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)

# Simulate data. y is some other variable whose value we'd like to keep at the
# minimum of x.
set.seed(1)
n <- 5e3
k <- 1 + rpois(n, 1)
dat <- data.frame(
  group = rep(1:n, k), 
  x = rnorm(sum(k)),
  y = sample(letters, sum(k), replace = TRUE)
)

# Obtain observation that minimizes x within each group
microbenchmark(
  slice = dat |> 
    group_by(group) |> 
    slice_min(x) |> 
    ungroup(),
  arrange = dat |> 
    arrange(group, x) |> 
    filter(!duplicated(group)),
  summarize = dat |> 
    group_by(group) |> 
    summarize(i = which.min(x), across(everything(), \(v) v[i])) |> 
    select(!i),
  times = 10
)
```

Performance:

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr        min         lq       mean    median         uq        max neval
#      slice 556.812802 625.876500 655.172451 632.45395 646.751201 909.931001    10
#    arrange   3.148302   3.209201   3.348941   3.34970   3.441501   3.663301    10
#  summarize  37.503501  37.946201  53.125181  38.17705  38.911001 127.843800    10
```

Comment: Here's a relevant github issue related to `slice_max` suggesting the arrange approach: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6783

Comment: You can take a look at the source code of `slice_min`, which has more things involved than you thought, which may increase the computational overhead. https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/50035835664d2a828d3ec019ddde2cec8932b1c3/R/slice.R

Answer (score 3):

A github issue related to the slow performance of slice_max with large numbers of groups has an author of `dplyr` suggesting a variation on your `arrange` approach that's even faster:
https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6783

```
 arrange2 = dat |> 
    arrange(x) |>
    distinct(group)
```

It sounds like the issue has to do with an inefficient handling of many groups.

```
Unit: milliseconds
      expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
     slice 518.743380 525.143223 532.999647 529.736452 535.752691 569.156511    10   c
  arrange2   2.049079   2.100594   2.260899   2.171024   2.419913   2.622632    10 a  
   arrange   3.354592   3.556705   3.641422   3.629209   3.720807   3.966684    10 a  
 summarize  42.778845  43.855632  49.064502  45.582195  47.292923  65.927071    10  b
```

Comment: but *why is slice_min() slow?* I like your answer, and alternative approaches and/or things it is related to are part answers, they don't answer the central question :-)

Comment: I'd like to know too! I'm afraid testing the source code to diagnose the performance bottlenecks is beyond my current abilities, but I'd be eager to learn from any others who can do a detailed analysis about what specifically makes the current implementation of `slice_*` slow for large numbers of groups. I hope it's incrementally helpful to suggest a code improvement and share some background on how the package developers are aware of (and presumably working on, with unknown priority) an improvement to this known issue.